# on click to close button of a modal load a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal having a close button like below.

```
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
```

When I click on the button close, I want to refresh the page which shows up after I clicked on closed or hit the esc button of my keyboard.

I tried with `onclick=javascript:window.location="/pages/test"`

But doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/s4e90rbg/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Bootstrap modal, this should do it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```